# Why does gitlab say i have tons of diffs even though i already merged the branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-diff

I am merging branch `X(feature)` into branch `Y(master)`

I merged branch X several times into branch Y.
Then I had the bright idea of merging `Y` into `X` as well.

Then I added some more commits to X, and opened a new merge request of `X` into `Y`.

Why does the diff count say all the files ever changed in X, and not just the latest commit that i added to X?

this is the graph.
the red is develop
the blue is master
the others are feature branches or release branches

[image]

Comment: You give us very little to work with here. Could you run a `git log` with graph which shows the history of X and Y?

Comment: `git log --graph` would be helpful

Comment: i added the graph as it is shown on source tree. I am not allowed to display the git log on stack overflow